# Replace Space to Hyphen

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to replace a space character into a hyphen I have in my string.

```
String replaceText = "AT AT";
replaceText.replace(' ', '-');
```

but when I do this, I cannot seem to replace the character. I tried the `replaceAll()` method and it doesn't work either.

**++++++Answer+++++++**

sorry my mistake.. the result of late night programming :(

thanks for the answer i cant probably answer all so i will check the first answer

```
replaceText = replaceText.replace(' ', '-');
```

Comment: i think the numerous answers below stress Strings are immutable. :)

Comment: @Brent: hmmm, maybe I need to make my answer stand out more: bigger, bolder text!

Comment: 6 more minutes to check an answer.. damn i hate this :(

Comment: Sleep deprivation is the #2 source of Stupid Programming Mistakes (SPIs). The #1 source, you ask? `!@#$%ing mondays`.

Comment: haha oh well deadlines deadlines deadlines :(

Comment: hey @Matt i shared that sentence as my personal sig :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
replaceText = replaceText.replace(' ', '-');
```

Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), they cannot be changed after creation. All methods that somehow modify a string will return a new string with the modifications incorporated.

Answer (score 13):

## **Strings are immutable.**

You need to save the value returned by `replace()`. <s>If you want to replace more than one occurrence, use `replaceAll()`.</s>

```
String replaceText = "AT AT";
replaceText = replaceText.replaceAll(" ", "-");
```

As [@Mark Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228171/mark-peters) points out in the comments, `replace(Char, Char)` is sufficient (and faster) for replacing all occurrences.

```
String replaceText = "AT AT";
replaceText = replaceText.replace(' ', '-');
```

---

In case this fact bothers you: [immutability is a `Good Thing`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493244/empirical-data-on-the-effects-of-immutability)

Comment: @Rob, hmmmmmm... I dunno... probably not?

Comment: Probably the are not... but that big-bold message makes me wonder.

Comment: [`replace(char, char)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) replaces all occurrences, as does the overload `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`.  Throwing regexes into the mix by using `replaceAll` is a step backwards since now you have to think about escaping special characters, and it will be less performant.

Answer (score 6):

The [`replace` and `replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) methods **return a String** with the replaced result. Are you using the returned value, or expecting the `replaceText` String to change? If it's the latter, you won't see the change, because **Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)**.

```
String replaceText = "AT AT";
String replaced = replaceText.replace(' ', '-');

// replaced will be "AT-AT", but replaceText will NOT change
```

Answer (score 5):

The replace method returns a String, so you need to re-assign your string variable i.e.

```
String replaceText = "AT AT";                         
replaceText = replaceText.replace(' ', '-');
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable.  You need to use the return value from replace:

```
replaceText = replaceText.replace(' ', '-');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/*You can use below method pass your String parameter and get result as   String  spaces replaced with hyphen*/
  private static String replaceSpaceWithHypn(String str) {
    if (str != null && str.trim().length() > 0) {
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        String patternStr = "\\s+";
        String replaceStr = "-";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        str = matcher.replaceAll(replaceStr);
        patternStr = "\\s";
        replaceStr = "-";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        str = matcher.replaceAll(replaceStr);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing many strings you want to consider using StringBuilder for performance.

```
String replaceText = "AT AT";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(replaceText);
sb.Replace(' ', '-');
```