# How to replace only the space character with something else

Tags: java

so I try this but it doesn't want to work the way i want it. I am trying to make a 'incrypting' program, so I've done this so far

```
    input = input.replace("a", "01100001\n");
    input = input.replaceAll("b", "01100010\n");
    input = input.replaceAll("c", "01100011\n");
```

this is what works, but here comes the problem:

```
    input = input.replaceAll(" ", "01000000");
```

not even "\s" or anything makes it work.

Anyone got any idea how to make it work so it only replaces the space character in between the words, Only them?   Thanks

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. That really should work - although I'd use just `replace` unless you *need* regular expressions.

Comment: NB: that is not the correct binary for a space - `01000000` is 64, representing the `@` sign.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262554/replace-space-to-hyphen this should help

Comment: And you are sure that `input` contains spaces?

Comment: Is your input type of String? What result do you get using input.replaceAll (" ","123) ?

Comment: What is your test string? We need to know in order to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
input= input.replaceAll("\\s+", "01000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String.replace()` not the `replaceAll()` method. The latter one expects a regular expression.

```
String s = "Hello World!";
String output = s.replace( " ", "-" );
```

Result:

```
Hello-World!
```

Also if you only need to replace space characters with just another character, you can use another overload of the `replace()` method which takes 2 characters and not 2 `CharSequence`s.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it wouldn't be working, `" "` not being anything special as a regex.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder aren't Java regexs implicitly anchored with `^$` ?

Comment: @Alnitak: Did you mean IMplicitly? No, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I must be misremembering (and yes, I did of course mean IMplicit)

Comment: unless it's not a real space - perhaps it's a unicode non-breaking space (0xa0) ?

Comment: @Alnitak OW WAIT! You are right, Alnitak! They *are* implicitly anchored with `^$`. `System.out.println("Hallo".matches("a"));` returns `false`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah, I was thinking of `String.matches()` which _does_ implicitly wrap the supplied regex in `^$`, e.g. `String.matches("abc", "a") == false`, but `String.matches("abc", ".*a.*") == true`.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes, I was overstating it when I said "regexs" - it's this one particular case.